# WMI: Cant configure using string came from database

Tags: c#

I am trying to configure ip of other pc. When i try to use normal string like this

```
string ip_address = "10.11.3.120";
```

it works fine. Now my main goal is to configure it in a dynamic way, so what i did i set those string on database and then loop it.
Now when I retrieve these data and do something like this

```
string ip_add = dr.GetString(0);

string subnet = dr.GetString(1);

newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_add };

newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet };
```

it's not working it also doesn't show any errors.

i have here the illustration working and not working.
[my sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXGzt.png)

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what the values of `ip_add` and `subnet` actually are?

Comment: What is the object dr?  Is it a datarow?  Did you try dr.Field<string>(0) and dr<.Field<string>(1)?

Comment: @Diado yes its working if i try to print it out.. the string that i declare is working. how ever if i try to declare to newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet }; its not working..

Comment: dr is data reader var query = "SELECT TOP 1 ip_address,subnet,gateway FROM computer_info WHERE pc_name = '" + hostname+"' ORDER BY id DESC";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: //string subnet_mask = "255.255.255.0";
string subnet = dr.GetString(1); the string subnet_mask is working rather than to string subnet. i dont why..